# Extra blank page after page with list

Tags: jasper-reports

[Here is my JRXML](https://www.szybkiplik.pl/download/04b1c156f7317201f7d1c17fcec10d10.html) On the second page I created a table using the nested list.   In Preview in Jaspersoft Studio everything looks good, but after generating PDF on the page where my nested list is, an empty page is added. I have no idea how I can fix this problem.

I tried:
Remove Line When Blank - for lists and fields.
When No Data Type - all options tried and tested.

I have a problem with generating an additional blank page in PDF. Our company system does not support generating reports from subreports to multiple pages. As a workaround, a 43 page printout was created and each page is divided by "Page Break". This works well. My data source is an XML file.

I've tried to solve previously given here in similar problems but it doesn't help.

I don't want to generate this empty page.

Part of nested list code:

```
<componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="240" width="555" height="40" uuid="5a5114e6-f143-4e73-9a70-6aa3285b4d31">
                </reportElement>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="OrderItems" uuid="a5783264-74e9-43b2-8312-84e805170f06">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("/wstxns1:XML/wstxns1:p7_Object/wstxns1:productOrder/wstxns1:items")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="40" width="555">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Table_TD" x="0" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="9f67e274-92bc-4a21-8403-d60b4115c5c3">
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement>
                                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{prospect/name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Table_TD" x="185" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="262d8477-4cdc-47dc-b746-b38793e05757">
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{totalReccuringChargeAmount}!=null)?(new BigDecimal($F{totalReccuringChargeAmount}).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)).toString() + " " + $F{totalReccuringChargecurrency}:""]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Table_TD" x="370" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="a9aad9d3-9269-427e-b0e7-032f582c44e7">
                            </reportElement>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{commitmentPeriod[Level0]}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="555" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="96c06463-aaa8-4ee9-80be-0110bbc8258c">
                            </reportElement>
                            <jr:list printOrder="Vertical">
                                <datasetRun subDataset="OrderItems" uuid="100d9171-37f5-45fc-b7b8-affe80e508af">
                                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("//wstxns1:items[wstxns1:itemId = '"+$F{itemId}+"']/wstxns1:configuration/wstxns1:prospect/wstxns1:children/wstxns1:items")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                </datasetRun>
                                <jr:listContents height="20" width="555">
                                    <textField>
                                        <reportElement style="Table_TD" x="0" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="1e3d8870-3a1f-4cd2-923d-ac1547d5805f">
                                        </reportElement>
                                        <textElement>
                                            <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["--"+$F{prospect/name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                    <textField>
                                        <reportElement style="Table_TD" x="185" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="8dee85a5-406b-4a81-ab42-1d29ade1ceab">
                                        </reportElement>
                                        <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                                            <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{totalReccuringChargeAmount}!=null)?(new BigDecimal($F{totalReccuringChargeAmount}).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)).toString() + " " + $F{totalReccuringChargecurrency}:""]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                    <textField>
                                        <reportElement style="Table_TD" x="370" y="0" width="185" height="20" uuid="80044161-2cc9-461d-bb6b-4b7426d9479c">
                                        </reportElement>
                                        <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                                            <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{commitmentPeriod[Level1]}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                </jr:listContents>
                            </jr:list>
                        </componentElement>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Table_TH" positionType="Float" x="185" y="280" width="185" height="30" backcolor="#D9D9D9" uuid="9e550a00-d376-4f3d-859e-9f3ebd875b76">
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{mainOrderTotalAmount}!=null)?(new BigDecimal($F{mainOrderTotalAmount}).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)).toString()+" "+$F{mainOrderCurrency}:" "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Table_TH" positionType="Float" x="0" y="280" width="185" height="30" backcolor="#D9D9D9" uuid="aa918c59-db11-49ad-8ab1-1e296b8e8b08">
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Total: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Table_CH" x="0" y="210" width="185" height="30" backcolor="#D9D9D9" uuid="5e3cea42-8937-4876-9ef3-4fef54ae66db">
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Package name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Table_CH" x="185" y="210" width="185" height="30" backcolor="#D9D9D9" uuid="a76bf537-65a0-400f-a75a-b0f03bd88796">
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Monthly charge]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Table_CH" x="370" y="210" width="185" height="30" backcolor="#D9D9D9" uuid="6893b476-bcc2-42ab-8078-364f13b6fcf6">
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contract period]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="750" width="555" height="40" uuid="eb235aed-5c5e-4ef3-b9ab-f776e5307aa9">
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[O749504]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
```

Any ideas guys? Maybe you need more details?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

Set the split Typ of the detail band to Stretch:

```
splitType="Stretch"
```

best wishes

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. I've checked it before. My .jrxml below. Maybe somebody will find problem in code. This is about Detail 2.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem. If the a list was the last item in the page in same cases a blank page was added.

When we added the whole list to a new band the empty page disappeared.